# How to get the probability density function from CoxPHSurvivalAnalysis in scikit-survival?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, survival-analysis, scikit-survival

I am using sksurv.linear_model.CoxPHSurvivalAnalysis to fit a cox ph regression and I would like to recover the density function f(t). The sksurv class has methods to predict the survival function and cumulative distribution function S(t) = 1-F(t) and the cumulative hazard function $H(t)$ but it doesn't seem to produce the density function.

My use case has no censoring, so ere is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sksurv.linear_model import CoxPHSurvivalAnalysis

data = np.random.randint(5,30,size=10)
X_train = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['covariate'])

y_train = np.array(np.random.randint(0,100,size=10)/100,dtype=[('status',bool),('target',float)])

estimator = CoxPHSurvivalAnalysis()
estimator.fit(X_train,y_train)

X_test = pd.DataFrame({'covariate':[12,2]})
chf = estimator.predict_cumulative_hazard_function(X_test)
cdf = estimator.predict_survival_function(X_test)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
for fn_h, fn_c in zip(chf, cdf):
    ax[0].step(fn_h.x,fn_h(fn_h.x),where='post')
    ax[1].step(fn_c.x,fn_c(fn_c.x),where='post')

ax[0].set_title('Cumulative Hazard Functions')
ax[1].set_title('Survival Functions')
plt.show()
```

[image]
How can I also access and plot the density function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability density function (PDF) can be obtained from the cumulative distribution function (CDF) as :

```
f(t) = dF(t)/dt
```

Now, in Survival Analysis (SA) the PDF `(f(t))` can be expressed in terms of Survival Function `S(t)` and the hazard function `h(t)` which is given by:

```
f(t) = h(t) x S(t)
```

where `S(t) = 1 - F(t)` and `h(t) = -dS(t)/dt x S(t) = dH(t)/dt`

So, the PDF `f(t)` can be expressed as :  `f(t) = dH(t)/dt x S(t)`

Now, to compute the hazard function `f(t)` we need derivative of Cumulative Hazard Function (CHF) `H(t)`. Since the CHF are all discrete data points, we need `InterpolatedUnivariateSpline` from the `scipy` library to differentiate it. It creates a smooth spline interpolation of the CHF, which can then be differentiated to obtain `h(t)`. Here's a slight modification of the code that was pasted:

```
# Import the necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sksurv.linear_model import CoxPHSurvivalAnalysis
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

# Define a function to compute the probability density function (pdf) 
# from the cumulative hazard function (chf) and survival function (sf).
def compute_pdf_from_chf_and_sf(chf, sf):
    # The hazard function is the derivative of the cumulative hazard function.
    # We use InterpolatedUnivariateSpline for spline interpolation to create a smooth 
    # function approximation of the CHF. This provides us with a smooth curve that 
    # passes through each data point, allowing us to differentiate the function and obtain 
    # the hazard function.
    chf_spline = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(chf.x, chf(chf.x))
    hazard_function = chf_spline.derivative()(chf.x)
    
    # The pdf can be computed using the formula: pdf(t) = hazard(t) * survival(t)
    pdf = hazard_function * sf(chf.x)
    return chf.x, pdf

# Generate random data for demonstration purposes
# Here, we create a random dataset with one covariate and survival times.

np.random.seed(42)  # Setting a fixed seed.
data = np.random.randint(5, 30, size=10)
X_train = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['covariate'])
y_train = np.array(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=10)/100, dtype=[('status', bool), ('target', float)])

# Initialize and fit the Cox Proportional Hazards model
estimator = CoxPHSurvivalAnalysis()
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict for new data points
X_test = pd.DataFrame({'covariate': [12, 2]})
cumulative_hazard_functions = estimator.predict_cumulative_hazard_function(X_test)
survival_functions = estimator.predict_survival_function(X_test)

# Plot the Cumulative Hazard, Survival, and PDF side by side in a single row
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 5))
for chf, sf in zip(cumulative_hazard_functions, survival_functions):
    # Compute the pdf using our defined function
    times, pdf_values = compute_pdf_from_chf_and_sf(chf, sf)
    
    # Plotting the cumulative hazard function
    axes[0].step(chf.x, chf(chf.x), where='post')
    
    # Plotting the survival function
    axes[1].step(sf.x, sf(sf.x), where='post')
    
    # Plotting the probability density function
    axes[2].step(times, pdf_values, where='post')

# Setting titles for each subplot
axes[0].set_title('Cumulative Hazard Functions')
axes[1].set_title('Survival Functions')
axes[2].set_title('Probability Density Functions')

# Display the plots
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which results in

[image: PDF]

References : [Machine Learning for Survival Analysis: A Survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.04649.pdf)

Comment: This worked, thanks! A follow up question: I expected the density function to look something like the histogram of the target or like the Kaplan-Meier curve computed from it. Do I have that wrong in some way?

Comment: @Kavyon: The Kaplan-Meier curve gives a general survival profile for the entire cohort, the Cox model's pdf is influenced by the covariates and provides survival information for specific profiles based on those covariates.

Thus, while there might be some similarities in the overall shape or trend between the pdf and the Kaplan-Meier curve, they are fundamentally different and might not match exactly, especially when the influence of covariates is strong.

Comment: May be you can review the Survey paper link that I pasted in my answer which will help you to give a very good understanding on the Kaplan-Meier (KM) curves.

Comment: Gotcha, yes that paper was helpful. Turns out I was thinking of the KM curve as estimating the density function but in fact it estimates the survival function. So the KM curve and the survival curve from cox-ph should be similar (different only for the influence of covariates), but neither of these are the density function so it shouldn't necessarily look similar.